# How to remove rows from Sub Objects in Acumatica?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, acumatica, erp

Its my day 2 with Acumatica and I have been tasked with integrating Acumatica with external application. I followed tutorials on this site:

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/technical-tuesday-connecting-website-acumatica/

to feed sample data into Projects object. Works great for inserts and updates

Sample code:
new Projects.Value{LinkedCommand = schema.ProjectSummary.ProjectID, Value = "18TDCN1033" },

new Projects.Value{LinkedCommand = schema.ProjectSummary.Description, Value = "Test Fixture 3" },

new Projects.Value{LinkedCommand = schema.ProjectSummary.Customer, Value = "BASFFE" },

schema.Actions.Save
};

scr.Submit(commands.ToArray());

How can I remove data populated in INTERNAL BROKERS sub-table for a project (***Please see snapshot***)? I would assume that these two tables share Project ID as common key.
[Project Details snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZJzQ.png)

Thanks

Manny

Comment: the url for the wsdl returns internal server error

Comment: What version of Acumatica build are you currently on? if 6.1 or greater I would suggest using the Contract based API for ease of use.